# Generating Dynamic SQL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate

I have a problem with my plsql code and try almost everything. Now i'm loosing my mind and power to solve my problem :)

The case is that I want to search all tables schema for specific string assigned to variable v_ss and print it to DBMS_OUTPUT. I know that there are ready-made solutions for that kind of cases, but I wanted to code it by myself. Below code gives me an error that "table does not exist" in my v_stmt. I assume that this select does not recognize rec.column_name, but why?

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
 v_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
 v_ss VARCHAR2(30) := 'Argentina';

 v_own ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER%TYPE;
 v_tab_nam ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;
 v_col_nam ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;

 CURSOR cur_asc IS
   SELECT t.owner, t.table_name, t.column_name
   FROM SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS t
   WHERE t.OWNER LIKE 'HR'
     AND t.DATA_TYPE LIKE 'VARCHAR2';


BEGIN
  FOR rec IN cur_asc LOOP
    v_stmt := 'SELECT rec.owner, rec.table_name, rec.column_name FROM rec.table_name WHERE rec.column_name LIKE :1';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt INTO v_own, v_tab_nam, v_col_nam USING v_ss;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_own || ':' || v_tab_nam || ':' || v_col_nam);
  END LOOP;


END;
/

Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 19
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Could You give me an explanation for my bug and how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic statement is executed in a context that cannot see your PL/SQL variables, so when it runs `rec.table_name` etc. are interpreted as SQL-level objects - which don't exist.

You have to concatenate the variable values into the dynamic statement for the `from` and `where` clause; you can do the same in the select list (though they'd need to be wrapped in escaped single-quotes as they are strings), or use bind variables there:

```
v_stmt := 'SELECT :owner, :table_name, :column_name FROM '
  || rec.table_name || ' WHERE ' || rec.column_name || ' LIKE :ss';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt INTO v_own, v_tab_nam, v_col_nam
USING rec.owner, rec.table_name, rec.column_name, v_ss;
```

You can't use bind variables for object identifiers, hence needing the concatenation for those parts.

Unless you run this as the HR user, in which case you could be using `user_tables` instead of `all_tables`, you also need to specify the schema in the query (As Tony and Lalit mentioned); either hard-coding HR or using the queried owner:

```
v_stmt := 'SELECT :owner, :table_name, :column_name FROM '
  || rec.owner || '.' || rec.table_name
  || ' WHERE ' || rec.column_name || ' LIKE :ss';
```

This is going to error for all the tables that don't contain exactly one matching value though - if the dynamic select gets zero rows, or more than one row. But that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here:

1. You need to concatenate the table and column names into the dynamic SQL because 'SELECT rec.owner...' is trying to select a column called `owner` from a table with alias `rec`, it does not reference your for loop record.
2. Since there could be no matching rows or many matching rows in a table, you cannot use `select into`, you need to use a cursor.

try this:

```
DECLARE
 v_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
 v_ss VARCHAR2(30) := 'Argentina';

 v_own ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER%TYPE;
 v_tab_nam ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;
 v_col_nam ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;

 CURSOR cur_asc IS
   SELECT t.owner, t.table_name, t.column_name
   FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS t
   WHERE t.DATA_TYPE LIKE 'VARCHAR2'
   AND ROWNUM < 10;

 c SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  FOR rec IN cur_asc LOOP
    v_stmt := 'SELECT ''' || rec.owner || ''',''' || rec.table_name || ''', ''' || rec.column_name || ''' FROM ' || rec.table_name || ' WHERE ' || rec.column_name || ' LIKE :1';
    OPEN c FOR v_stmt USING v_ss;
    LOOP
      FETCH c INTO v_own, v_tab_nam, v_col_nam;
      EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_own || ':' || v_tab_nam || ':' || v_col_nam);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: You got a typo since `USER_` view doesn't have owner column.

Answer (score 1):

> v_stmt := 'SELECT rec.owner, rec.table_name, rec.column_name FROM rec.table_name WHERE rec.column_name LIKE :1';

1. Your dynamic sql statement is malformed. If you enclose the variables between single-quotation marks then they are treated as literals and not variables any more.
2. You must prefix the **schema** before the table_name else you must run the script while you are connected as `HR` user.

```
v_stmt := 'SELECT '''||rec.owner||''', '''|| rec.table_name||''', '
                     ||rec.column_name||' FROM '||rec.owner||'.'
                     ||rec.table_name||' WHERE '||rec.column_name||' LIKE :1';
```

Always remember, whenever working with dynamic statements, always use **DBMS_OUTPUT** to first verify the actual SQL being generated. This is the best way to debug dynamic queries.

3. You need to handle **`NO_DATA_FOUND`** exception because it will throw error for all those tables which do not have any match for the filter you are using.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
  3    v_ss   VARCHAR2(30) := 'Argentina';
  4    v_own ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.OWNER%TYPE;
  5    v_tab_nam ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;
  6    v_col_nam ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;
  7    CURSOR cur_asc
  8    IS
  9      SELECT t.owner,
 10        t.table_name,
 11        t.column_name
 12      FROM SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS t
 13      WHERE t.OWNER LIKE 'HR'
 14      AND t.DATA_TYPE LIKE 'VARCHAR2';
 15  BEGIN
 16    FOR rec IN cur_asc
 17    LOOP
 18      v_stmt := 'SELECT '''||rec.owner||''', '''|| rec.table_name||''', '
 19                           || rec.column_name||' FROM '||rec.owner||'.'
 20                           || rec.table_name||' WHERE '||rec.column_name||' LIKE :1';
 21      BEGIN
 22        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt INTO v_own,
 23        v_tab_nam,
 24        v_col_nam USING v_ss;
 25        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_own || ':' || v_tab_nam || ':' || v_col_nam);
 26      EXCEPTION
 27      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 28        NULL;
 29      END;
 30      END LOOP;
 31    END;
 32    /
HR:COUNTRIES:Argentina

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Probably needs to handle too_many_rows too? Possibly with distinct but the use of 'like' might mean there could still be multiple matches, if v_ss has a wildcard.

Comment: Perhaps not for the standard HR schema without any manipulation/duplication. But in general yes, needs to be handled. Seems like OP is doing it for some learning purpose, else this approach should be avoided completely.